# Hive alter table column fails when it has struct column

Tags: hive, hiveddl

I've created hive external table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_db.test_table (
   `testfield` string,
   `teststruct` struct<teststructfield:string>
   )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   
   'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'        
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              
   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'       
 OUTPUTFORMAT                                       
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' 
 LOCATION                                           
   'hdfs://some/path';


hive> describe test_table;

+-------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
|  col_name   |            data_type            |      comment       |
+-------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
| testfield   | string                          | from deserializer  |
| teststruct  | struct<teststructfield:string>  | from deserializer  |
+-------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
```

and I want to alter table column. 
but when table has struct column (`teststruct`),
error occurs with `<` less than sign.

```
ALTER TABLE test_db.test_table CHANGE COLUMN testfield testfield2 string;

INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO  : Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null)
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Error: type expected at the position 7 of 'string:<derived from deserializer>' but '<' is found.
```

It succeed without struct column which has `<`. what should I do for this problem?

Comment: The table is EXTERNAL. You can drop it and create with correct definition and the data will remain as is

Comment: @leftjoin Yes it would, but table has many partitions and it is used by others. so If possible, I want to alter without drop..

Comment: Also you can create another external table on top of the same location and recover partitions. drop original one, rename table

Comment: @leftjoin Recover partitions could be done easily by MSCK. thanks! (MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else helps, as a workaround you can drop/create table and recover partitions. The table is EXTERNAL and drop will not affect the data.

(1) Drop table

```
DROP TABLE test_db.test_table;
```

(2) Create table with required column name

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_db.test_table (
   testfield2 string,
   teststruct struct<teststructfield:string>
   )
   PARTITIONED BY (....)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   
   'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'        
 LOCATION                                           
   'hdfs://some/path';
```

(3) Recover partitions

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE test_db.test_table;
```

or if you are running Hive on EMR:

```
ALTER TABLE test_db.test_table RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```