# Want to add a column to a Nested External Hive Table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I would like to add a column to an external Hive table that has nested structure. I tried `ALTER TABLE test_db.test_table ADD COLUMNS (col5 string)` . Obviously this didn't work. Please have a look at the SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_db.test_table`(
  `metadata` array<struct<field:struct<columnname:string>>> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `data` array<struct<col1:string,col2:string,col3:string,col4:string>> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `col6` string, 
  `col7` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://abc/qa/raw/def/hgj/analytics'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'spark.sql.partitionProvider'='catalog', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1639169673')
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69941711/2700344

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I considered dropping and recreating the table but the problem that table is simultaneously used by several other people. I would prefer altering the table without dropping the table.